# Adding Serial Numbers to a query in MySQL, while using ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to add a column for Serial Number in this query while using an ORDER BY condition. This messes the order of the serial number.

```
select @a:=@a+1 serial_number,users.user_name,
TRUNCATE(((SUM(transactions.t_qty*stocks.curr_price))+users.balance),4) as net_worth
from transactions natural join stocks natural join users,(SELECT @a:= 0) as serial_number
group by user_email order by net_worth DESC;
```

[image: Output]

I need serial_number to be in order while the other columns are ordered by net_worth.

Kindly tell me the changes to be made to get my desired output.

Comment: Don't post code or data as images: use text. Your experience here will be improved if you take the [tour] you were offered when you joined, and see [ask]

Comment: Oh ok will keep that in mind, I have edited it now

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Your edit is useless, as both images are still present, and you have not properly provided your table schema and the sample data using DDL and DML statements.

Comment: Alright I get that there are some insignificant errors I have made and I'll fix that. But I would appreciate an answer to my question along with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need `serial_number` to be a counter that starts at 1, I'd recommend to move your current query into a subquery and generate the counters at the outer query, something like

```
SET @a=0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 serial_number, user_name, net_worth FROM 
(select users.user_name,
TRUNCATE(((SUM(transactions.t_qty*stocks.curr_price))+users.balance),4) as net_worth
from transactions natural join stocks natural join users
group by user_email order by net_worth DESC) x;
```

You might also consider just generating the sequence numbers on the application side, which would make your database query simpler.

Comment: Wow thanks this works, could you tell me what that "x" at the end of the query is

Comment: Remove the x and run it and you'll see.  Every subquery has to have an explicit alias.